# How much of an effect does US withdrawal from the Iran deal actually have?

Tags: iran, sanctions, jcpoa

The US is just one nation -- what effect will US withdrawal have on Iran, assuming that other countries stick to the deal and impose no sanctions?

Answer (score 7):

There will be a huge ripple effect if the US imposes [secondary sanctions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Comprehensive_Plan_of_Action#Sanctions). Individual companies from the other signature powers would be sanctioned in the US for trading with Iran. The new US ambassador to Germany has [called on German](http://money.cnn.com/2018/05/09/investing/iran-sanctions-europe-business/index.html?iid=EL) companies to stop dealing with Iran.

Comment: Indeed [Airbus has already said it will abide by the sanctions](http://aviationweek.com/commercial-aviation/airbus-boeing-sales-iran-now-limits).

Answer (score 1):

There is concern that as the relationship between the US and Iran cools further, Iran might cleave closer to Russia and China. `[source](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2018/05/world-leaders-react-withdrawal-iranian-nuclear-deal-180508184130931.html)

Mohsen Milani's "The Making of Iran’s Islamic Revolution" is a good read, and I think it does a good job of telling the 20th century story (particularly how external powers manipulated the country). It's a good read now to understand how similar moves have played out in the past.

Comment: Only the first sentence really addresses the question; the others just reference a book and call it a useful read. And while that first sentence isn't wrong, the answer could definitely use some elaboration.